# Did Miles Dyson kill all these policemen?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

I stumbled upon [this recent question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9854/49) about [*Terminator 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/), in particular about the scene where *Miles Dyson* dies after having been wounded lethally and trying to buy time for the others by detonating a grenade. He warns the upcoming SWAT team that the grenade will go off shortly and they run away.

This question states that the policemen didn't have enough time to escape the explosion. But I for myself always thought they made it out of the explosion radius in time, but then again, I'm not totally sure about this anymore, since this question says they surely didn't have enough time as judged by the immediate cut to the explosion destroying the building (although I vaguely remember it to only destroy a single floor).

The reason I'm asking this is, that I think the fact of the policemen dying would bring a major inconsistency with the general moral justification of the heroes' actions throughout the movie. There are actually no real human enemies in this movie and the movie more than one time elaborates on the fact, that the heroes (and especially the supposedly good *Terminator*) don't kill anyone, in order for the viewer to better identify with them on a moral basis. Whereas the previous movie had that touch of sweet immorality, once you decided that it is *cool* to watch *Arnie* run around and kill everybody, this one goes to great lengths to show him as a *"good guy"*, especially in the scene more or less immediately before the questioned one. And in the end most action movies where the hero kills multiple bad guys in a row still try not to show him directly killing innocents.

So I see different possibilities for this:

- The SWAT team didn't die and managed to escape in time.
- Their death is to be justified as kind of collateral damage (in line with all the others killed by the *T-1000*, the "evil *Terminator*"), since *Dyson* didn't kill them completely on purpose.
- Their death is merely ignored or justified with a sense of "the end justifies the means" (which IMHO wouldn't be in line with the movie's previous moral elaborations, though).
- It is left open for the viewer to decide (which in turn was a bit too *"heavy"* an aspect for such a straight-to-the-point action movie).

And my question is, **did the SWAT team die from *Miles Dyson*'s grenade, and if yes, how is this supposed to be justified?**

(disclaimer: Now it might be that this has been intentionally left open for interpretation which would make this a bit of an open discussion question. But I might also just have overlooked something (or not remebering it that well) or there is even an official statement about this from the writers.)

Comment: Since this might provide some general insights into the moral justification of innocents killed by heros in movies, I hope the `analysis` tag is justified. Feel free to remove it if you don't think so.

Comment: Ahh all for the greater good!

Comment: BTW it's 'heroes' not 'heros'

Comment: I can't it's too small to be editable otherwise I'd have done it already

Comment: What? A movie like this is not about moral issues, it's almost not even about the story, Sarah Connor won't think twice before sacrificing an inocent in order to save the rest of the humanity, I mean even the kid is a thief, do you stop and think about whose money he is stealing from the ATM?, no no no, this movie is not about giving you a moral lesson.

Comment: @anakata Uh, but you did watch this movie, no?

Comment: Of course, are you kidding me? Robots from the future fighting for the fate of humanity!

Comment: Frankly, I never doubted that the SWAT team were meant to be portrayed as having escaped the blast. The movie makes such a big point about the good guys not taking human life (made abundantly and explicitly clear by John Connor during the "dipsh*t" scene assault). The fact that Dyson announces that he doesn't know how long he can hold on to the pressure switch and the SWAT officers get all panicky and run out is a very strong suggestion that they got away unscathed. I don't see the need to overthink this scene.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I stumbled upon this recent question about Terminator 2, in particular about the scene where Miles Dyson dies after having been wounded lethally and trying to buy time for the others by detonating a grenade. He warns the upcoming SWAT team that the grenade will go off shortly and they run away.

You are implying in the question that there was a moral line the film didn't want to cross. Where no humans are intentionally killed.

Except, Sarah goes to Dyson's home and shoots him in front of his wife and kid. Attempted murder is just as morally wrong as murder. The terminator then cuts the flesh off his arm to show he's a machine. So violence wasn't some hidden in the film.

I don't think the moral line is drawn in the sand as deeply as you imply, and the film was Rated R so there wasn't an issue with violence.

Still, the question isn't the morality, but if the police survived the explosions.

Here are a couple of facts, because I happen to be watching it on Netflix when this question came up.

- The police enter the science lab from the stairwell, and that is the same door they leave in when they run out.
- I was able to count to about 14 seconds from the time the police start moving before the bomb goes off.
- Sarah, Arnold and the kid are in the elevator when the bomb goes off, and have no problem surviving the explosion.
- The bomb doesn't destroy the floor. It only destroys the research lab on that floor (see image below). The fireball only comes out from a wide second, but clearly not the entire floor.
- When Arnold exists the elevator the same SWAT team is there waiting for them. They were able to get downstairs before the elevator. I was find the same actor playing a SWAT team member both before and after the bomb explosion (see image below).

*Explosion Of Research Lab*

[image: Explosion Of Research Lab]

*SWAT Team Member Before/After Explosion*

[image: SWAT Team Member Before/After Explosion]

So it's clear the SWAT team didn't die, and they actually appear again in the next scene. Sadly they are all shot in the leg by Arnold. Black guy with big explosive bomb zero points. Terminator with hand gun 10 points. You have to feel sorry to Dyson. First Sarah shoots him, then the swat team shoots him and then he blows up.

I'm going to watch the rest of the film. If I see anything else that I can add, then **I'll be back**.

Comment: *"Except, Sarah goes to Dyson's home and shoots him infront of his wife and kid. Attempted murder is just as morally wrong as murder."* - But the movie heavily emphasizes, that this was a hard decision she made and her son does not agree with this. She has to fight a moral struggle with herself and her son if she wants to buy a possible future by crossing the line and killing *Miles*, which she in the end doesn't.

Comment: *"So violence wasn't some hidden in the film."* - Of course it wasn't and *Arnie* freely hurts other people. But you seem to forget that the movie in various situations tries to emphasize that he *never* kills anyone and that this is completely no option for the human heroes at all, even if *Sarah* has a weak moment she could in the end withstand (as written above). Moral justification of the heroes' actions is not just about *R* rating vs showing them dance around a rainbow.

Comment: It may be that this isn't that much important for the end viewer (and I for myself wouldn't have cared *that* much if those policemen died as collateral in the explosion and would still stand by the heroes), but it is nevertheless a recurring theme of the movie. Showing violence doesn't have anything to do with it, never is anybody sadistically tortured by the heroes. *Arnie* still just shots them in the leg (*"Terminator with hand gun **0** points"*), no matter how much blood spills out from there.

Comment: But nevertheless the hard facts seem like the answer.

Comment: lol, you make me want to edit my answer and remove all that stuff. I think the conscience decision not to kill people was the boy's desired not to be like his mother. Where he states many times in the film how others saw her as crazy. I think it was a way for the writers to show his inner strength so that we could accept that one day he would become the leader of the resistance. He's the only person in the film who didn't see violence as the answer. This makes him a polar opposite of the terminator trying to kill him.

Comment: *"you make me want to edit my answer and remove all that stuff."* - You're of course free to do so and it would improve the answer by a large degree.

Comment: Out of Universe, there was a push back against overly violent movies like **Total Recall** and **Demolition Man**. There was supposed **body count** where the producers were trying to have the highest number of kills. When T2 came out, all the trailers showed the scene where Arnold raise his hand and says: "I swear I will not kill anyone."

Comment: I find a hidden reuse of stuntmen to be very poor evidence that the swat team upstairs was the swat team downstairs.

Comment: "Except, Sarah goes to Dyson's home and shoots him in front of his wife and kid. Attempted murder is just as morally wrong as murder." - However John talks her out of it before she delivers the *coup de grâce*, which highlights, and reinforces this moral message.

Answer (score 11):

I always assumed SWAT didn't die -- that Dyson was able to hold the detonator long enough for SWAT to get to safety.

If it's true that the scene-cutting didn't allow enough time elapse for the SWAT escape, I have to think this was an editing decision made for visual effect -- not to indicate that the SWAT guys were killed.

Killing SWAT would not add value to the story, but killing SWAT *would* add conflict with rest of the movie's "don't-kill-innocent-cops" theme.

Answer (score 1):

When the Terminator goes out into the parking lot and teargasses the cops he drives a Police truck back into the Cyberdyne building. As he does so the cops can be seen in the foyer trying to get to the front doors to leave, they scatter as the truck comes through the doors. Hope this ties it up.